# Regarding phpMyAdmin set up wizard

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up 'phpMyAdmin' according to a procedure, 'How To: 5 Steps to Install phpMyAdmin on Linux'.

Everything seemed ok. But when I tried to set up the phpMyAdmin wizard after entering my URL (http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php), I got an imcomplete set up wizard. I attached the image. [image]

If anybody had the same issue, could please share what was your solution? Many thanks!

Taehee

Comment: try [this](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install)

Comment: Thank you erapert! But, the result is the same even though I have followed your suggestion with manual configuration.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: I did use phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.1-all-languages.tar.gz, phpMyAdmin-4.5.1-english.tar.gz and phpMyAdmin-4.5.1-english.zip on OS X Yosemite (v. 10.10). And there was no any error report. I just followed the install process (http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install), and everything was fine without error. But, the set up wizard was always imperfect.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/setup/ but this server is not running on OS X.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your installation -- how did you install PHP and which version, are you using the included Apache or did you install a webserver on your own? I'm using the Apple provided Apache with Homebrew PHP 7 and this works fine for me. I believe you said phpMyAdmin works fine if you create `config.inc.php` manually, correct?